# How I can fix this array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, vector, fill

Good morning, I was trying to fill a dynamic vector but when I print the input data i get something like this:

```
input: 1,5,3,4,2
output: 0,1,5,3,4
```

Could somebody help me? I can't fix it. I've been trying a lot and can't get it. I'll apreciatte so much (sorry for the english)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STR 10

int vecto();

char seguir[MAX_STRLEN];
int var;

float* vector; 
char* bv;

int vecto(){
int cont=0,ch;
char v[MAX_STR];
printf ("¿number of elements to order?: ");
scanf("%d",&var);
vector = (float*)malloc(var*sizeof(float));
while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){};

printf("input number press f for finish \n");
    do{
        fgets(v,sizeof(v),stdin);
        if((strcmp(v,"f")!=0)){
            cont++;
            vector[cont]=strtod(v,&bv);
        }
    } while(!((cont==var) || (strcmp(v,"f")==0)));
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just got another error: the while loop is supouse to stop when I reach the total number of elements that I indicate before or when I input an "f" but i can't get it. When I input the "f" the loop continues until i `cont==var`
I change the condition to something like this but still can't :
`while(((cont<var) && (strcmp(v,"f")!=0)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment cont before you set the value.

Just swap the order

```
if((strcmp(v,"f")!=0)){
            vector[cont]=strtod(v,&bv);
            cont++;
        }
```

Comment: does the array starts at 0?

Comment: Yes. The first position of the array is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2 and so on!

Comment: I just got another error: the while loop is supouse to stop when I reach the total number of elements that I indicate before or when I input an "f" but i can't get it. When I input the "f" the loop continues until i `cont==var`
I change the condition to something like this but still can't :
`while(((cont<var) && (strcmp(v,"f")!=0)));`

Comment: You are using &&, which indicates that both conditions have to be true. Use `while(((cont<var) || (strcmp(v,"f")!=0)));` instead !

Comment: Try `while(((cont<=var) || (strcmp(v,"f")!=0)));`

Comment: I try this `while(!(cont==var || strcmp(v,"f")==0));` now works but can´t get out of the loop if I input f, only finish when `cont==var`

Answer (score 1):

You increment the `cont` and after that you use it. So first time it access the index 1 instead of 0.

Change it to:

```
if((strcmp(v,"f")!=0)){
   vector[cont++]=strtod(v,&bv);
}
```